# Overlay an image or PDF with images, text, and polygons in browser

Tags: web-apps, pdf, web-development, image-editor

I'm building a web application that will allow users to edit an existing document in the form of an image or a PDF (not both, either one or the other is acceptable), save the edits, and submit it back to the server. Specifically, I"m looking for a tool/tool stack that will facilitate the following:

- Get existing image or PDF from database on server, displaying it in the browser
- Supply the user with tools to edit the image/PDF in the browser

  - Overlay with an image
  - Add text
  - Add a polygon
- Save the edits to an image/PDF and resubmit to the database on the server (from the browser)

What tool best fits these requirements?

Comment: I know that PHP use GDgraph and other tools to easily handle image,text,polygons on an image, and it can definitely connect to most database types using PDO and a couple other techniques.  I am unsure about its PDF support.